# 5 stars rating script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing 5 stars rating script, but hes doesn't work properly, when cursor is on star he changes, but when you go on other star, what previous star is unselecting i need all stars go to select one by one like in normal ratings system.

```
$('.fa-star-o').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-star-o');
    $(this).addClass('fa-star');


}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('fa-star');
    $(this).addClass('fa-star-o');
});


                <div class="companies-list-item-rating">
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
                    <span class="companies-list-item-rating-count">/ 53</span>
                </div><!-- /.companies-list-item-rating -->
            </div><!-- /.companies-list-item -->
```

Comment: can you post  css here

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the current and previous stars and deselect all that follow after the current star..

```
$('.fa-star-o').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('fa-star');
    $(this).prevAll('.fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
    $(this).nextAll('.fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star');
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).parent().children('.fa-star-o').removeClass('fa-star');
});
```

Comment: I hope I understood your classes correctly. `fa-star` should be the enabled star and `fa-star-o` is a generic star class.. right?

Comment: You didn't use the script I've provided in my answer, jQuery library link is missing in your fiddle and the `fa-star-o` styling isn't defined. I've added a temporary styling to prove it works.. See https://jsfiddle.net/8o4cL1o1/11/

Comment: jquery is set in the javascript tab settings and font-awsome is loaded in the external resources, so fa-star and fa-star-o classes is setted (if you see in my fiddle example this classes working), i tried your script into my project and into fiddle still dont worked for me, with fa-star class.

Comment: As you can see in the fiddle, the `fa-star` class is added to the selected and previous stars (which in the fiddle shows as red background). There might be more problems in your project, but I'm afraid I can't help further. I hope you'll manage to find the problem.